# code access security in ASP.NET 4.0 and dynamic data error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have some problems with my MVC c# project.

First I receive this error: Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception. complete:

> Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Runtime.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace..ctor(System.String,
>   System.Guid)' to access security critical method
>   'System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace..ctor(System.String,
>   System.Guid)' failed.
>
> Assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is marked with the
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security
>   transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent
>   by default, which may be the cause of this exception."

Consequently I searched on the internet and two possibilities to solve it are found. The first works by including this snippet in `assemblyinfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
```

but nothing changed..

Googling I found a second information saying that If I place in `web.config` it probably work.

```
<trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full" />
```

But when I placed that info in `web.config` I receive and error like

> Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain

I don't know what else do I have to do...

I believe that using microsoft.practices.unity with ASP.NET 4.0 and mvc 4, is the main cause of the problem. But using unity for me is necessary based on the way my app works.

brgds! sebastian.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov do you know how to solve this issue?, thank you so much in advance..

Comment: @marc-s thank you for the ediition... do you have any idea of why this could be possible?. brgds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET 4.0 framework, new CAS model prevents any security transparent code to call into security critical code

From the exception that you've described above, it seems that both the methods that you call belong to a an external library (namespace System.Runtime.Diagnostics), and not to your code or even your assembly.

The fact that one external library method throws when trying to access another method of that library, indicates the possibility of a bug in that library or some sort of a binary or configuration mismatch issue (according to this thread [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/a8ceb77b-f625-4259-94de-4ae5157ba98c](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.fulltrustassembliessection.aspx))

"legacyCasModel" switches to non-homogeneous (or simply CAS 1) app domains. This means that dynamic and the older CAS setting is incompatible. Moreover, MVC 3 used dynamic in its own code (please see ViewBag dynamic in ASP.NET MVC 3), so most likely, MVC 4 does the same.

Instead of switching to legacy cas 1, you could try adding the assembly with System.Runtime.Diagnostics namespace to FullTrustAssembliesSection of your web.config file

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.fulltrustassembliessection.aspx

Comment: hi I work on the proposed solution. I have one doubt, if I use fullTrustAssemblies its neccessary to use publickey or I can use publickeytoken.. I cannot find the way to see publickey of system.servicemodel ... brgds!

Comment: @sebastian_h: According to the documentation, you need public key. To see public or public token, could you try (from VS command prompt) sn -Tp System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll?  For more information, see Sn.exe (Strong Name Tool) documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx. Also, I would try executing the same scenario on a different machine just to make sure that .NET Framework and ASP.NET are correctly installed and configured on your dev box

Comment: thank you so much, yes finally I found the public key using vs command prompt but everything remains the same. I believe that I have to remove everything and reinstall net framework and asp.net. despite the fact that I restore both installations yesterday it seems that it has something related with that. probably when I tried VS2011 with .net 4.5 something was changed... thank you so much for your support!. brgds

Comment: Always glad to help :). >when I tried VS2011 with .net 4.5... I had a similar problem - had to re-install everything after that :(

Comment: yes, I believe I have to do the same...thank you so much! brgds